# Alternative to while loop

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am a newbie. I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37527932/699305) earlier regarding retrieving duplicates of the data i need from the db, for example the opening times from each takeaway duplicating on each take away (see image below); and i received a very helpful comment. The comment suggested that my while loop is causing my problem of query results duplication, as it is overriding my data.

[duplication example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wv3nE.png)

After looking at my code and working out which while loops are causing this problem (as I have a few), and playing around with them to understand my issue, I am now intrigued to know what loop can be used in replacement or as alternative to a while loop.

```
  $rest_query = "SELECT Resturant_ID FROM Rest_Details";
  $res_results = $dbc->query($rest_query);

   //while($row_results = $res_results->fetch_assoc()){
    $row_results = $res_results->fetch_assoc();{
    {
         $rests = $row_results['Resturant_ID'];
     }
   }
```

Above is one of the while loops I have removed, I know I will need a loop to gain all the information needed. And I do not know the number of repetitions I will need, therefore a for loop is not helpful.

Just trying to gain a better understanding, as I am building this website to teach myself.

Comment: Consider using an abstraction layer like Zend_Db.

Comment: I don't think the problem is your while loop, but your SQL. Or, if you want to avoid joins/aggregations, you need to rethink the way you are fetching data. Maybe you use ActiveRecords, or just populate arrays inside your while loop.

Comment: How about cleaning up the data to remove the duplicates and make the database not have them in the first place?

Comment: @EdHeal the only duplicates in the db are the day number. Which i cannot get past

Comment: @FelippeDuarte i agree with you. I have been looking and testing my sql for the last hour and i found the issue is that query, as it is only retrieving the last result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"SELECT DISTINCT my_column_with_duplicates FROM Rest_Details"
```

and then

```
while($row_results = $res_results->fetch_assoc())
```

will work just fine.

Also there are other ways like $res_results->fetchAll() to get all the results in an array then use foreach loop. Just an idea.

Comment: Looking at the image, I don't think `DISTINCT` is the answer here.

Comment: I'm guessing there's a variety of SQL problems in different places; the query in _this_ question could well be improved by `DISTINCT`. One thing at a time.

Comment: it partly works. But did did indeed help the issue, thank you